# jquery clearing textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm not sure why I am having this issue, if you can help I would appreciate it.

I wrote a function to clear a textbox on click, but it isnt working correctly:

```
$(function() 
{
    $('textarea#contact_t').click( function() 
    {
        if ($(this).val() == 'Enter your message Here!') 
        {   
            $(this).val('');    
        }
    });
});
```

The problem is that it will not allow me to write a value of  '' to the textarea. This same function works if I change the statement inside the if to $(this).val(' ') (with a space in between the quotes). But I want the textbox to be cleared, not have a space at the beginning. It isn't letting me write an empty string to the textarea.

Comment: It seems ok to me (in Chrome at least): http://jsfiddle.net/xzHAX/1/

Comment: ok so kind of funny reason why it wasnt working. I had this function as well:

$(function() {
 $('body').click(function(el) {
 
  if (el ! = $('textarea#contact_t')) {
 
   if (current_page == 'contact' && $('textarea#contact_t').val() == '') {
     $('textarea#contact_t').val('Enter your message Here!');
   }
  }
  });
  });

So and since the textarea element is obviously a child of body, it was clearing it and then re-putting it in the box.

Comment: Posting code in comments like that is difficult for the reader.  Since you solved your own problem... please post it as an answer below and accept your own answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This does what (I think) you want (and is a little cleaner):

```
$('textarea#contact_t').one("focus", function() {
  $(this).val('');
});
```

Comment: That is cleaner, I switched to that. It turns out the .click and val() also worked though, it was a different problem with a different function.

Comment: There is no point adding `textarea` at the start. Finding by ID is much faster.

Comment: @lolwut: You're right it's pointless, but really: How much faster? This is a good solution, but be careful when the field is prepopulated (maybe after a server side validation error). The user will lose their data and be twice as annoyed.

Comment: While we are on the general topic, if I have a body.click function and I want to exclude a particular child element, is there code that can do that? @WesleyMurch

`<code>like function ($(this)) {
  if $(this) != $(#contact_t)
       body.click...etc

}</code>`

Comment: sounds like you're talking about the :not selector http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/ but best to open a new question

Comment: @Wesley Murch: See here in this test I made: http://jsperf.com/textarea-id-vs-id -- there is still some significant slowness on prepending `textarea`.

Comment: @lolwut: Thank you for introducing me to **jsperf.com**! Your test actually showed it was quite a big difference, I was quite surprised.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code... I bet it solves your problem...

```
$(function() {
    $('textarea#contact_t').click( function() {

         if ($(this).val().toUpperCase() == 'ENTER YOUR MESSAGE HERE!') {  
            $(this).val('');  
         }

    });
  }
);
```

Comment: You're missing the parentheses after `text`, and you don't want to be assigning an empty string to the method (you want to be passing the string into the method as an argument).

Comment: @JamesAllardice -- yeah good points.  Thinking about it, I'm guessing it is a case issue, so I changed to the fix for that.

Comment: Ahh good thinking, that could well be the problem. There's no reason it shouldn't work provided the value of the `textarea` is actually equal to the string given.

Comment: ...but why would OP say a space `$(this).val(' ')` does in fact work? Maybe it's not a lower/uppercase issue. It looks like he wants a placeholder text, so he should know the exact string anyways.

Comment: If you look at my response to james in his first comment youll see why it was happening. it was my ('body').click function that was reweriting any null value.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live without supporting older browsers, just drop the jquery and switch to the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute:

```
<textarea placeholder="Enter your message here"></textarea>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UeuaW/

Comment: The rest of my site ive made sure has worked in all browsers (even ie7) so Id rather not start coding only for newer ones now. Thanks though, the placeholder tag is cool.

Comment: OK, a lot of people aren't aware of it and write hacks for it. Your code works for me already, but I'd change the event to focus and in fact use [Alex's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862463/jquery-clearing-textarea/7862487#7862487).